# Replacing only some line endings with a tab delimiter

Tags: python, python-2.7, fasta

I currently have a FASTA file with several DNA sequences in it.

The lines alternative between a descriptor: “>\w{4}\d{6}”
And a DNA sequence file - a line of 300+ random capitalized alphabetic letters.

I am trying to make each sequence tab delimited, so that each descriptor and sequence is on a single line, separated by a tab. The following is what I have tried:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re
import sys

Fasta_seq = open(sys.argv[1])
for a_line in Fasta_seq:
  if re.search('^>.+', a_line):
     re.sub('.+\n', '.+\t', a_line)
     print(a_line, end='')
  else:
    re.sub('.+', '.+', a_line)
    print(a_line, end='\n')
```

However, this code does not seem to delete the line ending at the end of my descriptor. It simply returns to me the exact same output.

Does anyone have an idea of what I am overlooking?

Comment: Right after the `for a_line in Fasta_seq:`, add an indented `a_line = a_line.strip()` before the `if` line. Also remove the `end='\n'` on the `print` in the `else` clause.

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes, I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: @Martineau It seems that your code worked. However, my tab after the descriptor isn't appearing as I would have assumed it would in the "if" statement. Can you understand why? It's almost as if my re.sub function isn't working.

Comment: The `a_line.strip()` removes the newline at the end of each line read, so there's no trailing `\n` to match. Frankly I don't know why you're using `re` for this at all. After stripping the line, just check if the line starts with a `'>'` or not. If it does, print it with a `end='\t'`, if not, just print it normally (using the default `end='\n'`).

Comment: @martineau True, you're right... Just did that with like 8 lines. Thanks. Still curious why my 're' doesn't work, but that's a good suggestion.

Comment: As I was trying to indicate, it's probably because after the `a_line.strip()` there's no longer a newline at the end of the string—so the `'.+\n'` pattern in the `re.sub()` call doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are dealing with leave or interleave fasta, but this task can be easily done without regular expressions (also, use 4 space indents). Try the following:

```
Fasta_seq = open(sys.argv[1])
output_file = open("outfile.txt", "w")

seq = ""

for a_line in Fasta_seq:

    if a_line.startswith(">"):

        # Do this only when a sequence has been populated
        if seq:
            output_file.write("{}\t{}\n".format(header, seq))

        header = a_line.strip()
        seq = ""

    else:
        seq += a_line.strip()
```

This should work in both leave and interleave fasta inputs